# Why does SWI-Prolog fail when mentioning a predicate without any facts in a rule?

Tags: prolog

Here is my Prolog program:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose, silent).
:- initialization(main).

:- use_module(library(tabling)).

:- table reachable/1.

reachable(X) :- start(X).
reachable(X) :- reachable(Y), link(Y, X).

start(london).

% link(london, paris).
% link(paris, london).
% link(london, frankfurt).
% link(paris, frankfurt).
% link(frankfurt, paris).

main :-
  forall(reachable(X), writeln(X)),
  halt.
main :-
  halt(1).
```

Running it gives this error:

```sh
swipl links.pl
Initialization goal raised exception:
ERROR: 'reachable tabled'/1: Undefined procedure: link/2
```

However this works:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(verbose, silent).
:- initialization(main).

:- use_module(library(tabling)).

:- table reachable/1.

reachable(X) :- start(X).
reachable(X) :- reachable(Y), link(Y, X).

start(london).

link(tokyo, hongkong).

main :-
  forall(reachable(X), writeln(X)),
  halt.
main :-
  halt(1).
```

```sh
swipl links.pl
london
```

How can I make my program work with and without and `link` facts?

---

```sh
swipl --version
SWI-Prolog version 7.6.4 for amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to dynamically add the facts to the database later (for example via `assertz/2` or `asserta/2`) you should use the directive [`dynamic/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(dynamic)/1):

```
:-dynamic link/2.
```

This prevents bugs in your program due to typos.

Comment: Your answer could help Prolog programmers of all systems if you removed "when using SWI":)

Comment: @repeat not really all systems but probably the ones updated in the last 15 years

Comment: Right, only ISO-Prolog systems. On the other hand, "ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995" will be turning 30 pretty soon!